# autoloading css files for templates

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, twig

I've made a simple MVC framework based on some tutorials in youtube
my files structure is like:

```
assets
  |----->css 
  |----->js

conf
core
mvc
  |----->Models
  |----->View
  |----->Controller
  index.php
...
```

It has a very basic `.htaccess` that will route all requests to `index.php`

I will use twitter bootstrap also.

My Questions are:

1. where should I load my css files ? in each View ?
2. Where should I load my js files ? in each View ?
3. Is there a way to autoload each View's css and js files dynamically ?

**Edit:**

I'm using Twig templating, if that helps to answer

Comment: I did a micro frameword too and i had the same doubt, in my case i am loading CSS and JS files in each View. With PHP and Smarty i got this dynamically.

Comment: I think this is the last choice :(

Comment: I think Twin supports loading css files , I've seen somewere

Comment: Smarty was great to me, it did everything i need until now. But if you are already using Twin, i agree that can be a little complicated to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use .htaccess to redirect the root of app to index.php, the folder of index.php will be mapped as the root of your app in URL. It's '.'.

So, the path to CSS files is './assets/css/*.css' and the path to JS files is './assets/js/*.js'.

All assets should be loaded into the rendered view. But, you don't have to load these assets in each template of view.

Since you are using Twig template system, you can prepare a base template to load the most common CSS & JS files. Then, in each child template, you only need to load the specified part. Please refer to [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#template-inheritance).